# Wrong number of Facebook checkins via Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, json, facebook-graph-api, sdk, checkin

I have a Facebook page integrated with spot and it has checkin counter(ex: 90 were here)
 in the left of the page.
Now I can access the page using facebook Graph API Exploler like follows.

https://graph.facebook.com/page_id

In the result of JSON format, there is the field as follows.

  "can_post": true, 
  "checkins": 88, 
  "type": "page"

This says there are total 88 checkins on my spot of the Facebook page.
But, the checkin counter in my Facebook page says, it's 90.

Why there is a little difference between page counter and graph API?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Those are different numbers.

- The one you see in the web interface is ***X** people were here* -
- The one exposed in the API is ***Y** checkins occurred here*

If I check in somewhere and tag 3 friends, X goes up by 4, Y goes up by 1

If I check in another time and tag the same 3 friends, X stays the same, Y goes up by 1

Comment: Thank you lgy. I understand the each value.<br>

Comment: Is it possible to get the X value via Graph API or FQL??

Comment: Currently no, i'm not aware of any way to get the number of distinct users that have checked in via the API

Comment: Does it mean API can't catch up with the progress of Facebook??

Comment: I've tried to checkin tagged with a friend, but the counter goes up by only 1 both in the facebook page and in the Graph API Explorer. Why??

Comment: No, I selected the place where we've never checked in. Therefore I wonder why not... What is the problem? Thanks, lgy.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still having the same problem. The checkins counter is deprecated as are checkins themselves, see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/

> NOTE: Publishing a Checkin object is deprecated in favor of creating a
>   Post with a location attached.

Luckily, via FQL you can now get the `were_here_count` field of a page instead. This field shows exactly the same # users as is shown on Facebook itself.