# Get # People that "Were Here" from a facebook page with FQL

Tags: facebook-fql, facebook-page, facebook-checkins

I am trying to get some statistics for a facebook page using publicly available information - particularly how many people have ever been tagged at that place.

I used FQL to retrieve the # of checkins for a specific `page_id` - which works fine.  Query: `SELECT checkins FROM page WHERE page_id=PAGEID`.

However I noticed that the # of checkins is a different number than the number that is listed on the facebook page ie. *"4,600 Were Here"*.

So I have two questions.

1. If somebody checks into a place and tags 4 other friends there with them, does that only increment the field "checkins" by 1 or by 5?
2. Is it possible to get the number of individual people that "were here" (ie. the number that is listed on the facebook page)?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Anyone who is experienced please answer this question. Thanks for your time..

Answer (score 0):

I think this issue is discussed here:

[Wrong number of Facebook checkins via Facebook Graph API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049504/wrong-number-of-facebook-checkins-via-facebook-graph-api)

I am having the same problem. Basically, the API returns number of users who checked in, but the "were here" count returns number of users who checked in + no. of users they tagged with them. The "were here" count is not accessible via the API.

...*I think*...